# Groups from TimeGrouper starting at first index

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to group a dataframe with time index by 3 hours intervals. It is sampled at a frequency of 1.5 s. I would expect the following to return a single group of length 4323.

```
import pandas as pd
time_grouper = pd.TimeGrouper("3H");
dataframe.groupby(time_grouper).count()
```

Output:

```
2013-02-23 06:00:00    1733
2013-02-23 09:00:00    1149
Freq: 3H, Name: roll, dtype: int64
```

If I change the time grouper frequency to 1000 s, I get:

```
2013-02-23 08:03:20    133
2013-02-23 08:20:00    667
2013-02-23 08:36:40    666
2013-02-23 08:53:20    667
2013-02-23 09:10:00    667
2013-02-23 09:26:40     82
Freq: 1000S, Name: roll, dtype: int64
```

**Edit**
From the comments I understood that the resampling starts at 00h00:00 which explains the seemingly uneven bins. How can make resampling start at the beginning of time range covered by the indexes?

Comment: what time range does your original data span?

Comment: But what is the start and end datetime? It will probably be easier if you show a small reproducible example (eg with date_range)

Comment: Pandas just starts counting at `00:00:00`, not at the beginning of your data to determine the splits, *otherwise* it would be unpredictable. Eg `08:03:20` (8*3600+3*60+20 = 29000) is a multiple of 1000S.

Comment: Please include a sample `dataframe` definition

Comment: @joris: Thanks, this explains the second example. But I still don't understand why a split occurs in the first case. Any idea?

Comment: @firelynx: I am trying to reproduce the first example with date_range but failed up to now.

Comment: @AlfredM. in the first example you are resamplng every three hours. Pandas starts hourly resampling at 00:00, adding three hours each. So you get a group starting at 03:00, 06:00, 09:00, etc. Your data falls into the 06:00-09:00 and 09:00-12:00 ranges which is why they are returned

Comment: @k-nut: Okay, so this is indeed the same reason behind both cases. How can make resampling start at the begining of the time intervall ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible workaround using `pd.cut()` to construct the categorical group manually.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt

# simulate some artificial data
# ==================================================
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(4500), columns=['col'], index=pd.date_range(dt.datetime.now(), periods=4500, freq=pd.Timedelta(1.5, 's')))

                               col
2015-07-15 11:41:05.987156 -0.1191
2015-07-15 11:41:07.487156 -0.4531
2015-07-15 11:41:08.987156  1.2682
2015-07-15 11:41:10.487156 -1.3194
2015-07-15 11:41:11.987156  0.2690
2015-07-15 11:41:13.487156  0.3139
2015-07-15 11:41:14.987156  1.3467
2015-07-15 11:41:16.487156 -0.0090
2015-07-15 11:41:17.987156 -1.4792
2015-07-15 11:41:19.487156 -0.6973
...                            ...
2015-07-15 13:33:20.987156 -0.6072
2015-07-15 13:33:22.487156  0.2621
2015-07-15 13:33:23.987156 -1.1274
2015-07-15 13:33:25.487156  0.9305
2015-07-15 13:33:26.987156  0.4124
2015-07-15 13:33:28.487156 -0.8061
2015-07-15 13:33:29.987156 -0.0065
2015-07-15 13:33:31.487156 -1.3291
2015-07-15 13:33:32.987156  1.1309
2015-07-15 13:33:34.487156 -0.6444

[4500 rows x 1 columns]


# processing using pd.cut
# ==================================================
ts_rng = pd.date_range(df.index[0], df.index[-1], freq='3H')
# string format for labels
ts_rng_iso = [x.isoformat() for x in ts_rng]
# groupby the categorical variables
df.groupby(pd.cut(df.index, bins=ts_rng, labels=ts_rng_iso[:-1], right=True, include_lowest=True)).count()


                             col
2015-07-15T11:41:05.987156  4500
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Do you know how to modify your code so that the remaining data are put into a group of smaller size?

Comment: You can replace '3H' with the frequency you want, see [offset aliases](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases).